# Question regarding the Lebesgue outer measure and open intervals.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

[image]

Here $\lambda^*$ is the Lebesgue outer measure.

Possible proof:

Assume first that $\lambda^*(E)$ is finite.

By the definition of Lebesgue outer measure, there exists sequence of open intervals $\{I_n\}$ s.t $E\subset \cup_n I_n$ and $\lambda^*(\cup_{n} I_n) \leq \sum l(I_n)< \frac{1}{\alpha}\lambda^*(E)$
where $l$ is the length function.

Suppose for contradiction that all $I_n$ do not meet the required condition in the question.

Hence, for all $n$: $\lambda^*(E\cap I_n)< \alpha \lambda^*( I_n)$

This implies that $ \lambda^*(E)=\lambda^*(E\cap \cup_n I_n)\leq \sum \lambda^*(E\cap I_n)\leq \sum \alpha \lambda^*( I_n)= \alpha\sum l( I_n)  $. This is a contradiction according to the definition of $I_n$.

If $\lambda^*(E)$ is infinite that we can take $I$ to be R

Is this proof valid?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: May I ask what textbook you are using?

Comment: The pic was taken from my lecture notes.